# C# windows form GUI multithreading

Tags: c#, multithreading, user-interface, backgroundworker

I'm new to C#, and i'm trying to write a GUI application.
I want my application to represent some charts on the GUI, after Button_1 is clicked.
The amount of charts is known during runtime only.(I don't know how many charts should be before the app is starting to run).

When Button_1 is pressed, I want create a new thread, which will create new threads itself, according to the number of charts.(every chart would be build by a different thread).
The main thread(Form) will only add charts to the Form.control to avoid Form window to freeze.
Which is the best way to implement such app? Backgroundworkers? Threads?

How chart-building-threads should send the charts which they've created to the father thread, which should pass them to the main thread of the Form.

Comment: Have a look at WPF MVVM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, a solution where `Controls` are created on background threads is not possible with Windows Forms, which are not threadsafe.  `Controls` are only permitted to be modified on the thread that created them, so there's no safe way to create one on a background thread and then turn over control to the UI thread.